# Get value from the AJAX call made in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am working on a test, that will check that a link present on a page and it's referencing to the correct page (link generated dynamically). To test the link I want to make an AJAX call in Selenium, to get the correct URL from the server and compare it. My challenge is to get value from the AJAX call made in Selenium.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String jsCode = 
            "var str = $.get('/User/GetDynamicURL/', function (result) {"
                        + "console.log('result: ' + result); "
                        + "return result;"
                    + "})"
           + "return str;";
String dynamicURL = (String) jse.executeScript(jsCode);
```

My code doesn't work although I see expected output in console. 
I get exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

When I execute the code:

```
    var str = $.get('/User/GetDynamicURL/', function (result) {
                    console.log('result: ' + result);
                    return result;
                });
    str;
```

for `str` in console in my browser I get an object that looks like:

`{readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

and `str.responseJSON` returns the desired URL

Please advise me how I can fix my code.
Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with the Library you are using, but casing `String dynamicURL = (String) jse.executeScript(jsCode);` clearly is the Problem. Write `com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap dynamicURLMap = (String) jse.executeScript(jsCode);` and then check dynamicURLMap, which values it contains. One of those values will be what you're looking for.

Comment: @JayC667, I tried the next code inspired by lukeis [recomendation](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5154)

  `Map<String,Object> result = (Map<String,Object>) jse.executeScript(jsCode);`  

result doesn't contain expected value

Comment: Tried his last response too?

Answer (score 0):

The link must be a webelement, right? So you can just get it's href value to compare with expected URL (as a String maybe):

```
String expectedURL = "https://whatever...";
String linkURL = driver.findlement(locator).getAttribute("href");
Assert.assertEquals(expectedURL , linkURL);
```

Comment: My problem in getting the expectedURL because it’s generated dynamically (by server) and I need to get it from server to compare with href .